# Find the greatest line

Tags: code-golf, array, matrix

You will be given a 2-D array A of integers, and a length N. Your task is to find within the array the straight line (horizontal, vertical or diagonal) of N elements that yields the highest total sum, and return that sum.

#### Example

```
 N = 3, A = 
 3    3    7    9    3
 2    2   10    4    1
 7    7    2    5    0
 2    1    4    1    3
```

This array has 34 valid lines, including

```
 Vertical
 [3]   3    7    9    3
 [2]   2   10    4    1
 [7]   7    2    5    0
  2    1    4    1    3       [3,2,7] = 12
 Horizontal
  3    3    7    9    3
  2    2   10    4    1
  7    7   [2]  [5]  [0]
  2    1    4    1    3       [2,5,0] = 7
 Diagonal
  3    3   [7]   9    3
  2    2   10   [4]   1
  7    7    2    5   [0]
  2    1    4    1    3       [7,4,0] = 11
```

The maximum line is

```
 3    3    7   [9]   3
 2    2  [10]   4    1
 7   [7]   2    5    0
 2    1    4    1    3        [7,10,9] = 26
```

Note: lines may not wrap around the edges of the array.

#### Inputs

- A X by Y 2-D array A, with X,Y > 0. Each element of the array contains an integer value which may be positive, zero or negative. You may accept this array in an alternative format (e.g. list of 1-D arrays) if you wish.
- A single, positive integer N, no greater than max(X,Y).

#### Output

- A single value representing the maximal line sum that can be found in the array. Note that you do **not** need to provide the individual elements of that line or where it is located.

#### Test cases

```
N = 4, A = 
-88    4  -26   14  -90
-48   17  -45  -70   85
 22  -52   87  -23   22
-20  -68  -51  -61   41
Output = 58

N = 4, A =
 9    4   14    7
 6   15    1   12
 3   10    8   13
16    5   11    2
Output = 34

N = 1, A = 
 -2
Output = -2

N = 3, A =
1    2    3    4    5
Output = 12

N = 3, A = 
-10   -5    4
 -3    0   -7
-11   -3   -2
Output = -5
```

Comment: Could you add a test case where the resulting output is negative? Like `[[-10, -5, 4],[-3, 0, -7],[-11,-3,-2]]` -> `-5` (`4 + -7 + -2`)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Sure, added

Comment: By the way: all answers with an explanation will gain an upvote from me, but otherwise I have no way of judging languages that I'm not familiar with (and that's most of them).

Answer (score 10):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 15 bytes

```
,ZṚ¥;ŒD$+⁹\€€FṀ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVAxbgJBDOzvFS7o2BXYtwuHaFH@EC5X0kR8IF2SJ6RMH9HwgWuJ8hD4yDLjW0VIluwdj2fsfT0cj2@lhP11/L78bP@@drP57WN8uX2eEU/X8b38nmzxXErfSN@3QRCyDrJBNYRGpLcgCF0GSUgTBgKCeA6y/OcpsOSpHQi2gaKx64CzEW2FSllt6lRMbCrUYoJWXMNHujw1xSAasxEiw7icWZ00UOOqI0NZubu6cXJjHuH7JN5UJbGBZloiVyXerO6LXK9WbgqeUtUeROP0UH@o/03rX5Onk5vhDg)

#### How it works

```
,ZṚ¥;ŒD$+⁹\€€FṀ  Main link. Left argument: M (matrix). Right argument: n (integer)

 ZṚ¥             Zip/transpose and reverse M. This is equivalent to rotating M 90°
                 counterclockwise.
,                Pair M and the result to the right.
    ;ŒD$         Append the diagonals of both matrices to the pair.
        +⁹\€€    Take the sums of length n of each flat array.
             FṀ  Flatten and take the maximum.
```

Comment: Nice abuse of `¥` there...

Comment: For future (new) users: `$` creates a monad from `ZṚ`, while `¥` creates a dyad from `ZṚ` which returns the result of the same function (rotate 90 CCW) applied on its left operand. Which matches the pattern `+ ×` and evaluate `v+(λ×ρ)` (it is `v = v , (M ZṚ¥ n)` in this case). However just use `$` doesn't work because there is no `+ F` pattern in dyadic chain.

Answer (score 6):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 73 bytes

```
Max[Tr/@Join[#,#,{#,Reverse@#}]&/@Join@@Partition[#2,{#,#},1,1,-∞]]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY2xCsIwFEV3fyPgdIPNa9rGQcgsCEXcSocgFTNYoUYRSmbd/AM/zh/wE@orDiJvuHDu5byDC/vm4ILfumF3bhfDyl2rTTezy6NvKwHxftzQC6ybS9OdGitiPf2W1pauCz74I@9o3IgIxSdf92ddT4ey822wLK00@l4aAw1JORTHPInopTZQBaTOIIsEJmNGBJkRDGNKQTTOKIHMDXN25wpaxVhPfnY12umfpcwUCCn/zLgaPg)

### How it works

Takes first `N` and then the matrix `A` as input.

`Join@@Partition[#2,{#,#},1,1,-∞]` finds every `N` by `N` submatrix of the matrix `A`, padded with `-∞` where necessary to ensure that lines running out of the grid will be out of the running.

For each of those blocks we compute `Tr/@Join[#,#,{#,Reverse@#}]`: the trace (i.e. sum) of each row, the trace (i.e. sum) of each column, the trace (*actually* the trace, for the first time in the history of Mathematica code golfing) of the block, and the trace of the block reversed. `#` is `Transpose@#`.

Then we find the `Max` of all of these.

Comment: For *most* inputs, the 57-byte `Max@BlockMap[Tr/@Join[#,#,{#,Reverse@#}]&,#2,{#,#},1]&` also works. But we need to pad with `-∞` to handle cases where `A` has fewer than `N` rows or columns, and `BlockMap` doesn't support padding.

Comment: For TIO-friendly version (Mathematica script mode): The character U+F3C7 (`\[Transpose]`) can be typed in as `\:f3c7`.

Comment: Also I believe it is not the first time `Tr` is used as trace.

Comment: Thanks! And when I'm not exaggerating, I'm sure using `Tr` as the trace of a matrix has come up before, but it's still rare and surprising.

Comment: I know I've said that before, but non-ASCII code should work just fine now. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY2xCsIwFEV3fyPgdIPNa9rGQcgsCEXcSocgFTNYoUYRSmbd/AM/zh/wE@orDiJvuHDu5byDC/vm4ILfumF3bhfDyl2rTTezy6NvKwHxftzQC6ybS9OdGitiPf2W1pauCz74I@9o3IgIxSdf92ddT4ey822wLK00@l4aAw1JORTHPInopTZQBaTOIIsEJmNGBJkRDGNKQTTOKIHMDXN25wpaxVhPfnY12umfpcwUCCn/zLgaPg "Wolfram Language (Mathematica) – Try It Online")

Comment: Is that new? I feel like I tried `∞` an hour ago and it didn't work, but maybe I just made a mistake.

Comment: It didn't work an hour ago. I'm using a workaround to make TIO's Mathematica accept UTF-8 code, but that broke with the update to 11.2.0. I just fixed it again.

Comment: Well, thank you for making the workaround work: we all appreciate it, as do our byte counts.

Comment: If anything else doesn't work as it should, please feel free to leave me a message in http://talk.tryitonline.net.

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, <s>135</s> 123 bytes

```
Max[(s=#;r=#2;Max[Tr/@Partition[#,r,1]&/@Join[s,s~Diagonal~#&/@Range[-(t=Tr[1^#&@@s])+2,t-1]]])&@@@{#|#2,Reverse@#|#2}]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY/BasMwEETv/QqBICR0RKyVHTsEgw49FQoh5GZUEMVJDY0DsikF17n22E/tJ7irnBoKErszO3qsTr5/rU@@b178dBClmJ78RzXvSrkJpaRNVPuwtFsf@qZvzm0lEaDdbGkfz01bdeguD40/nlv/dpHs7nx7rCs178t9qPSznFnbucU9oVfaObdgbQf58/31KQm7@r0OXW0li9HNpm1o2l7YQzUMBgY51jAjBgJBJ0ihWeRsEzIk14GOLodGGHf357kqCp4oWkFzWcewSgvoHCrNoPIERRYBBJURCrbJgCjGKIFaFexrrszXDE9v4GuIFILBIh8hhhX3GV8@FLXhJoEouJioNQfinAPELHELU1dP33iaf2h4/@z/v5isMqRxUQPu89gxmtWVZNz0Cw)

Comment: Some optimizations: `Diagonal[s,#]` to `s~Diagonal~#`, and `{{Transpose@#,#2},{Reverse@#,#2}}` to `{#|#2,Reverse@#|#2}`. (The unprintable is U+F3C7 = `\[Transpose]`; TIO doesn't seem to like this, though. Alternative: `{Transpose@#|#2,Reverse@#|#2}`)

Comment: @JungHwanMin It's not TIO's fault, Mathematica on TIO is run in script mode, which only support ASCII. You need to type `\[Transpose]` or `\:f3c7` (at least the latter is shorter than `Thread@`) However if the answer is Mathematica REPL (not Mathematica script) you can assume the 3-byte solution.

Comment: @user202729 Thanks, didn't know!

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 16 bytes

```
µ;Z;Uµ;ŒDðṡ€ẎS€Ṁ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///QVuso61AgeXSSy@END3cufNS05uGuvmAQtbPh////0cY6CkBkrqNgCWTE6ihEG@koAJGhgY6CCZACiZiD5YGCpjoKBlAlhhBpkJ7/xgA)

Comment: Wow our solutions are nearly identical... Mine was `µ;Z;UŒD$;ŒDṡ€⁴ẎS€Ṁ`

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Oh wow cool :P

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript, <del>151</del> 129 bytes

```
a=>n=>a.map((l,x)=>l.map((v,y)=>[...'01235678'].map(d=>m=(g=i=>i--&&g(i)+(a[x+d%3*i-i]||[])[y+i*~-(d/3)])(n)>m?g(n):m)),m=-1/0)|m
```

Curry function takes two arguments, first one is an array of array of numbers, second one is a number.

Thanks to [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld), save 20+ bytes.

```js
f=

a=>n=>a.map((l,x)=>l.map((v,y)=>[...'01235678'].map(d=>m=(g=i=>i--&&g(i)+(a[x+d%3*i-i]||[])[y+i*~-(d/3)])(n)>m?g(n):m)),m=-1/0)|m
```

```html
<p><label>N = <input id="N" type="number" min="1" value="3" /></label></p>
<p><label>A = <textarea id="A" style="width: 400px; height: 200px;"> 3    3    7    9    3
 2    2   10    4    1
 7    7    2    5    0
 2    1    4    1    3
</textarea></label></p>
<input value="Run" type="button" onclick="O.value=f(A.value.split('\n').filter(x=>x.trim()).map(x=>x.trim().split(/\s+/).map(Number)))(+N.value)" />
<p>Result = <output id="O"></output></p>
```

Comment: `1/s` instead of `s==s` should work as expected.

Comment: Getting rid of both eval's: [130 bytes](https://tio.run/##TY/dboMwDIXveQpuVuxCApR17EfJ3mAvQJGalR9lSgARVlEJ7dVZA506X3z28Tmy5C9xFubUy24gTVuUc8VmwXjDuKBadAAqGJFxtYpzcLmKjFLqRfEu2T@lz16@WAXjmoFhUDPJuCRks6lBog8iG/3iIdlKIvNpynLMLr7c/hAowgRzhAaR63fzqhEDzUgcRjjp2bCjm7jXWpBavCzScXe2W8SRnR4tYmfNpH@eu7eIbun4HlyOHN8c1zm1jWlVSVVbQwWGmk7JAbxD4yGtpBrKHkbGRzr0UgPi8uW/xS0fHowfrubHt/4se0SEBHH@BQ)

Comment: @Arnauld Thanks. And change `(s=(g=...)(n))>m?s:m` to `(g=...)(n)>m?g(n):m` save 1 byte.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jq 1.5](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 211 bytes

```
def R:reverse;def U:[range(length)as$j|.[$j][$j:]]|transpose|map(map(select(.))|select(length>=N));def D:U+([R[]|R]|U|map(R)[1:]);[A|.,transpose,D,(map(R)|D)|.[]|range(length-N+1)as$i|.[$i:$i+N]]|max_by(add)|add
```

Expects input in `N` and `A`, e.g:

```
def N: 3;
def A: [
  [ 3, 3,  7, 9, 3 ],
  [ 2, 2, 10, 4, 1 ],
  [ 7, 7,  2, 5, 0 ],
  [ 2, 1,  4, 1, 3 ]
];
```

Expanded

```
def chunks:      .[] | range(length-N+1) as $i | .[$i:$i+N] ;
def flip:        [ reverse[] | reverse ] ;
def upperdiag:   [ range(length) as $j | .[$j][$j:] ] | transpose | map(map(select(.))|select(length>=N)) ;
def lowerdiag:   flip | upperdiag | map(reverse)[1:] ;
def diag:        upperdiag + lowerdiag ;
def allchunks:   A | ., transpose, diag, (map(reverse)|diag) | chunks ;

[allchunks]|max_by(add)|add
```

Note this challenge is basically the same as [Project Euler problem 11](https://projecteuler.net/problem=11)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU5Na4QwEL37K3LwkGCUtbulNLKFBc8eBE8hlLSmu4obrYn9gPz22km2LEvDTOYNb@bN69/XVr2hiqFtEXl0YIhHKDyOttQHeqDoERAS9MrcUR/5hqIdlFsGhiE8e0/R5t9ODswuFFCLRBGO12xWH2o2qvBdw/gs9VHhQemjPRFp4t5lPO4FJBPCWaDNNBrlznLCPo0a1KvFGSHuD152n/YVIUG0ZE2Cec2Fq4VrwmJNeM4EKfjBZfSqSUuKL6wrCZwV7tZMWiW5N9R5Qx2Lu6QCQ2f59fzyjWXbEgffuv6Mk@1GbdY01cswpJ2eFgvNLD/TcbHQ/AI)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>208</s> <s>184</s> <s>183</s> 176 bytes

- Saved 24 bytes by using `-float("inf")` to represent that the checked line reached outside the matrix instead of computing the negative sum of all matrix elements.
- Saved a byte by defining `R,L=range,len` to shorten built-in functions and using `y in R(L(A))...R(L(A[y]))` instead of `y,Y in e(A)...x,_ in e(Y)`.
- Saved seven bytes by golfing `float("inf")` to `9e999`.

```python
lambda N,A:max(sum(A[y+q*j][x+p*j]if-1<x+p*j<L(A[y])>-1<y+q*j<L(A)else-9e999for j in R(N))for y in R(L(A))for x in R(L(A[y]))for p,q in[(1,0),(0,1),(1,1),(1,-1)]);R,L=range,len
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVFLb4MwDL73V0Q9kTWZcCA8tjKp96qHXhkHpsFG1QKFTmp/PbNN1Wk9bNOmoeDYnx@f7bSnw2tTm6FMHodtvnt6zsVKLe52@dHp33bOIj3N9jebLD3OWryqUsOc1fmSfJl8QIBDCJDFti90XMRxXDad2IiqFmtnJSVZp9GiMLaPF5vqMNSqPYKpA8qVynEVoISz1CAzeb9Wy6TL65dCbYt6yPu@6A6idDwl0hQFnlCJGJUMEaMEHnCV8PEiJGQ/glYJ9xwCo5tyMim@/pJEmGByofWJVkcRV9AmwDKkxFxa@4gD0mkf2XSIbUSWOZFUWxQROQ32bAwnGAzRQUReII06A2oKaW10RRuPbeMfUjJxWx4DuJg3Dk4t8C4g4KEBA8z3c16m9fwPWuBpf5z96w9ptZl8flvgV/N4Zvs/HSAtXNNq2qHGvfn8QIiRzQvXtEpC/rgRmtZO2q6qD2K6asTYQNXUoui6putvp8M7)

## Explanation

```python
lambda N,A:                                                                                                                                                       ;R,L=range,len # lambda function, golfed built-ins
           max(                                                                                                                                                  )               # return the maximum line sum
                                                                                          for y in R(L(A))                                                                       # loop through matrix rows
                                                                                                          for x in R(L(A[y]))                                                    # loop through matrix columns
                                                                                                                             for p,q in[(1,0),(0,1),(1,1),(1,-1)]                # loop through four directions; east, south, south-east, north-east
               sum(                                                                      )                                                                                       # matrix line sum
                                                                            for j in R(N)                                                                                        # loop through line indices
                                  if-1<x+p*j<L(A[y])>-1<y+q*j<L(A)                                                                                                               # coordinates inside the matrix?
                   A[y+q*j][x+p*j]                                                                                                                                               # true; look at the matrix element
                                                                  else-9e999                                                                                                     # false; this line cannot be counted, max(...) will not return this line
```

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 199 bytes

```r
function(m,n,i=1,j=1){y=1:n-1
x=j-y;x[x<1]=NA
y=i-y;y[y<1]=NA
'if'(i>nrow(m)|j>ncol(m),NA,max(c(v(m[i,x]),v(m[y,j]),v(m[b(y,x)]),v(m[b(y,rev(x))]),f(m,n,i+1,j),f(m,n,i,j+1)), na.rm=T))}
v=sum
b=cbind
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVLbTsMwDH3PV0QIiUQkCId2K4Mg8QM88VYmtBUKqZZMKmO0Ar59JHYZ4yL64No5ts@xk3ZT2039HKqVWwbhVVDOgmosyNfewiRoYJ1tdH/Wld05TO3VJeuti3Ff9kN84OoD4S5Cu3wRXr41F6FaLqKnri6Vn3WiEmvhS6e6qVTJ61UzeHPRq07uBO39WnQyndSk5TBq2QaqOQQpFQ@zo9bbaynf2do@PXs2t9XchbuN55Yv3NNKMEY/b9sECMZ5JU4Ujx/ZMdpTOpEKcYMRWjhGP0MLAz7eqaTcHO3xt3rYrRz6x4RgE81PWZXQRbEt0GaE5OifprYRzxCHRKuzRKjHKK7IEecm0eocyQvMMjiiMVRvUrYeFZgF6KOsDEhW9qesYTXZVk8cnPhIYv41HxARLXZYHGk@QQBGX7sC2ogZqNlvbm0Qgt9I7DTJ/10lkWvSlpEqTfdNCI2gSQUh2ny2lIzVy1a4W89d4DBZ3IeH1WN8x5LxarYS8RGWZUSn032vtm6Qau8m7Em2@QA)

A recursive solution. For each element (i,j) of the matrix it returns the max between the sum along the row, the sum along the column, the sum along either diagonal, and the result of the function applied to (i+1,j) and (i,j+1).
Results for the test cases are shown in the TIO.

Comment: I hope I missed it, but R seems to be lacking a base function to compute the trace of a square matrix.

Comment: Haven't worked out if it would save you bytes, but you can use sum(diag(m)) for the trace

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 14 bytes

```
▲mΣṁX⁰ṁëIT∂(∂↔
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9G0TbnnFj/c2RjxqHEDkDq82jPkUUeTBhA/apvy//9/4//R0cY6xjrmOpY6xrE60UY6RjqGBjomOoZAjjlQ2EjHVMcALGEIEgUqigUA)

Thanks to the new anti∂iagonals builtin this is a quite short answer :)

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript 170 bytes

still wip on the golf part
added 4 more chars because i didnt managed a case where the max is negative and N is bigger than 1

```js
M=-1e9
G=(A,N)=>eval(`for(y in m=M,A)
for(x in R=A[y])
{for(a=b=c=d=j=0;j<N;d+=Y[x-j++])
{a+=R[X=+x+j]
b+=(Y=A[+y+j]||[])[x]
c+=Y[X]}
m=Math.max(m,a||M,b||M,c||M,d||M)}`)

console.log(G([ [3,3,7,9,3],
 [2,2,10,4,1],
 [7,7,2,5,0],
 [2,1,4,1,3]],3)==26)
 
 console.log(G([[-88,4,-26,14,-90],
[-48,17,-45,-70,85],
[22,-52,87,-23,22],
[-20,-68,-51,-61,41]],4)==58)

console.log(G([[9,4,14,7],[6,15,1,12],[3,10,8,13],[16,5,11,2]],4)==34)

console.log(G([[-2]],1)==-2)
console.log(G([[1,2,3,4,5]],3) ==12)
```

Comment: @HermanLauenstein i remove the spaces but added more coverage which added in total more chars, but thx :)

Comment: [164 bytes](https://tio.run/##bVCxbsIwEN39FRlj@YxiJyGJ6FViYoKBCWRZwiRpSwSkAoSCGr49PSMm2uWsu/fuvXtu3NWdy9Pu@yKPbVUPwxylqgs2w3AKC47v9dXtw81Hewpvwe4YHHAOU@7bzrdLnJqb5T9@4HCLJVbYYDRp3haTSuDadLIRgghO4NKsUHSisWwrMFzTprhR1/fGctNZVnr@yt7Jwl2@RgfXhQdwfT@HrS@lLxUVft/woWyP53Zfj/btZzgLTWBiiCGDAmILLDAaNKgIElCPNiNIQwrRE1QeIaqFmCPqMWcBC14kjcxzokk9BkVP4XeNTHJQGcgkBZlFkKd@qDXIVENOcx2D1g@ijkCOcwIUveSnyCwhszTnjL1aFf6eBDILhtxSuk2RCmWiDGRImYwa0/1KgX7qxMk/OtKjilCp@R@QdumPEkgfsQNEpfnwCw) by removing unnecessary newlines (`G=` is not counted)

Comment: Why did you use `a||M,b||M,c||M,d||M` instead of `a,b,c,d`?

Comment: @HermanLauenstein Math.max(NaN/undefined, 6) = NaN

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>222</s> 218 bytes

```python
n,a=input()
W=len(a[0]);Q=['']*W;R=range;a+=[Q]*n
for l in a:l+=Q
print max(sum(x)for y in[zip(*[(a[j][i+k],a[j+k][i],a[j+k][i+k],a[j+k][i+n+~k])for k in R(n)])for j in R(len(a)-n)for i in R(W)]for x in y if''not in x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU9Nb4JAEL3zKyZeAJlN2JUvNfwIvXjY7IFY1FVciMUUe@hfpzPQpk0IO/PevDdvuld/aZ0aj@1bXS4Wi9FhVVrXPfsg9A5lU7ug0rEJt7tS@75ZHrb78lG5c72tolLvzNJ5p/YBDVgH1aaJyp3XPazr4V4NwfvzHgwh8y/i9aftgqUmv6vRNroZpIoebf@q/2jkoq@bmeQ3tt8HLpzb69xO4ULhJszO2CE03A3c0dKT77u252YIRzrP8z4utqlBbuqhPgJfPa4QtKYffTnCmgpDiEJQKGOEBEEykE80wSlC/DMhZ5olxkvYRxQFAoFCZUTQu6ZZLRJCZY4iSVHkZFqkhIJSKFKyKYhRtF4pnlUxiqwgRtLLG@SvOYdLkFwhZ3mGMuXtkmUUn9MWKCm@lhnnlKRWJJZTMq6mWyUqXGGCqTHf)

Comment: Possible [219 bytes](https://tio.run/##TY5NjoMwDIX3nMI7EnAlYFpVnYpLsGFheZFFf1KoQQyVoIu5OuPASDNSlLz3@dlOP4/3ToplEXSll/41GhvVZXsR4yhje67KwcntcnZpSRTHnNScSHTtBmjBC7jPVguBS9QPXkZ4usl8vZ5msiE0a4jevjcJ6cAHk08bRlX6kP9T/2kq6XfDa3sTdlRG7GYfm11/Z3eyMr@x2nJwU3C69BrH0o3BTHZZPhCI9NJzRDipYCUFQoF5hrBHyAM4rmXFB4TsN5Fv5dDCPw).

Comment: Possible [218 bytes](https://tio.run/##TU9Nb8IwDL3zK6JcaGgikdDSQpUTv4BdOEQ5VFMZgRIqVrSyw/56Z7ubNikf9nv283P37E@3aMad5ZyPUdY2xO7RJ6I62LaJSe2WXlR76zj3i0P1Yu91fGuqOrVu7xdxdrzdWctCZPW2Te1@1t1D7Nm1HpL3xzUZBPJP4N1n6JKFA72zdyG9eAkRfC78Rf/RNKZfF0/tF5R/SaKY0vOUkjmhImFhwg7CYzZgBkOP83m89ZgMYoT1qmZoXvnHKbQN220xYTs@riRzDh44hWQbCDwgRjI4eilZBh8iBfEA5pItf0r0RGOPn2UopMoSMcXMGgiA1IaKVQa4BgGVQb8qQLjMSQVkVA5PiaQBF8ZQg4EStS6R1RjhLP07ZjMNhltgMc7KyYim5tVkHUfSNnpNtjUUGJDQ5BQjWl7TWiuSzL3/Bg).